# Get the year of the latest available data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to get the year of the latest available data for each combination of country(iso3), indicator(gho_id),gender(sex), type of residence(location). The data are stored in "gho_value".
My dataset looks like that:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 6
   iso3  gho_id sex   location  year gho_value
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2000      28.6
 2 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2001      28.8
 3 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2002      29  
 4 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2003      29.2
 5 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2004      29.4
 6 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2005      29.5
 7 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2006      29.7
 8 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2007      29.8
 9 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2008      29.9
10 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2009      30.1
11 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2010      30.2
12 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2011      30.3
13 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2012      30.4
14 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2013      30.5
15 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2014      NA
16 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2015      NA
```

I would like to have this:

```
# A tibble: 16 x 7
   iso3  gho_id sex   location  year gho_value last_year
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2000      28.6      2013
 2 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2001      28.8      2013
 3 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2002      29        2013
 4 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2003      29.2      2013
 5 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2004      29.4      2013
 6 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2005      29.5      2013
 7 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2006      29.7      2013
 8 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2007      29.8      2013
 9 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2008      29.9      2013
10 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2009      30.1      2013
11 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2010      30.2      2013
12 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2011      30.3      2013
13 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2012      30.4      2013
14 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2013      30.5      2013
15 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2014      NA        2013
16 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2015      NA        2013
```

I have tried to use the tidyverse package (dpylr) and did this:

```
ungho2 <- left_join(ungho,
            ungho %>%
            arrange(iso3,gho_id,sex,location,year) %>%
            group_by(iso3,gho_id,sex,location) %>%
            filter(!(is.na(gho_value))) %>%
            mutate(latest_year_gho = last(year)) %>%
            ungroup(iso3,gho_id,sex,location))
```

My problem is that I get this (NA instead of 2013 when I use left_join):

```
# A tibble: 16 x 7
   iso3  gho_id sex   location  year gho_value last_year
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2000      28.6      2013
 2 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2001      28.8      2013
 3 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2002      29        2013
 4 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2003      29.2      2013
 5 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2004      29.4      2013
 6 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2005      29.5      2013
 7 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2006      29.7      2013
 8 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2007      29.8      2013
 9 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2008      29.9      2013
10 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2009      30.1      2013
11 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2010      30.2      2013
12 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2011      30.3      2013
13 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2012      30.4      2013
14 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2013      30.5      2013
15 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2014      NA        NA
16 AFG   BP_04  FMLE  <NA>      2015      NA        NA
```

What could I do?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: without knowing dplyr it seems that you are skipping the `gho_values` that are `NA` (`!(is.na(gho_value))`). The last 2 rows don't have a value, so there is no `last_year` value (and I guess it is filled with NA).  I may be wrong though.

Comment: In base R, you can just do `ungho$last_year <- max(ungho$year[!is.na(ungho$gho_value)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using `dplyr`, here's a simple solution:

```r
df <- data.frame(iso3 = rep("AFG", 16),
          gho_id = rep("BP04", 16),
          sex = rep("FMLE", 16),
          location = rep(NA, 16),
          year = seq.int(2000, 2015),
          gho_value = as.numeric(c(28.6, 28.8, 29, 29.2, 29.4, 29.5, 29.7, 29.8,
                                   29.9, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, NA, NA)))


library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # Group by the variables you wanted to
  group_by(iso3, gho_id, sex, location) %>%
  # Get the max year when `gho_value` is not NA for each group defined above
  mutate(last_year = max(year[!is.na(gho_value)]))
```

Comment: Excellent answer, I was thinking the same thing

Comment: Perfect! it does the job and way easier..Thank you.

Comment: If the entire serie is NA then I don't get any result. How can I turn it into last_year=NA?

Comment: You mean that that for a given unique group if `iso3`, `gho_id`, etc..., `gho_value` is completele `NA`? You want  for that specific scenario for the `last_year` to be `NA`?

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, paste0(df$iso3, df$gho_id, df$sex, df$location)),

       function(x){x$last_year <- max(x$year[!(is.na(x$gho_value))]); return(x)})), row.names = NULL)
```

Tidyverse solution (handling case when the entire series is NA):

```
require(dplyr)

df %>%

  group_by(iso3, gho_id, sex, location) %>%

  mutate(last_year = ifelse(all(is.na(gho_value)), NA, max(year[!is.na(gho_value)]))) %>% 

  ungroup()
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(iso3 = rep("AFG", 16),

          gho_id = rep("BP04", 16),

          sex = rep("FMLE", 16),

          location = rep(NA, 16),

          year = seq.int(2000, 2015),

          gho_value = as.numeric(c(28.6, 28.8, 29, 29.2, 29.4, 29.5, 29.7, 29.8,
                         29.9, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, NA, NA)))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R`, I guess the following code might help (assuming `df` is `data.frame` for your data)

```
df$last_year <- df$year[tail(which(rowSums(!is.na(df[-4]))==ncol(df[-1])),1)]
```

which gives

```
> df
   iso3 gho_id  sex location year gho_value last_year
1   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2000      28.6      2013
2   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2001      28.8      2013
3   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2002      29.0      2013
4   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2003      29.2      2013
5   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2004      29.4      2013
6   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2005      29.5      2013
7   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2006      29.7      2013
8   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2007      29.8      2013
9   AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2008      29.9      2013
10  AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2009      30.1      2013
11  AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2010      30.2      2013
12  AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2011      30.3      2013
13  AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2012      30.4      2013
14  AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2013      30.5      2013
15  AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2014        NA      2013
16  AFG  BP_04 FMLE     <NA> 2015        NA      2013
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(iso3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "AFG", class = "factor"), 
                     gho_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "BP_04", class = "factor"), 
                     sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "FMLE", class = "factor"), 
                     location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "<NA>", class = "factor"), 
                     year = 2000:2015, gho_value = c(28.6, 28.8, 29, 29.2, 29.4, 
                                                     29.5, 29.7, 29.8, 29.9, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, NA, 
                                                     NA)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```